# Flattening a dictionary <str, list> into a comprehensive list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've got the following dictionary from a server request:

```
dict = {"first": "Mark", "last": "Zuckerberg", "alternative": ["Zuck", "Facebook guy"]}
```

Which I'm looking to convert into a list like this:

```
result = ["Mark", "Zuckerberg", "Zuck", "Facebook guy"]
```

I'm really trying to keep it pythonic for personal satisfaction I guess. The closest I've been to is this, which you can tell it only gives me the nested list instead of what I'm actually looking for.

```
values = list(dict.values())
result = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist if isinstance(sublist, list)]
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
def flatten(s):
    for e in s:
        if isinstance(e, (tuple, list)):
            yield from flatten(e)
        else:
            yield e


d = {"first": "Mark", "last": "Zuckerberg", "alternative": ["Zuck", "Facebook guy"]}

result = list(flatten(d.values()))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Mark', 'Zuckerberg', 'Zuck', 'Facebook guy']
```

The `flatten` function will deal with arbitrary nested lists.

Comment: I noticed something funny... I have two available python versions on my system. Python3.5 randomly returns any order while python3.7 returns the correct order every time. Any idea why?

Comment: It must be because in python 3.5 dictionaries are not ordered

Comment: As for order as docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict say: *Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.*